# How to use aggregation '$out' to migrate data between collections, but different database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I am using aggregation framework to to migrate data from one collection to another. The following is the sample of code:

```
db.oldCollection.aggregate([{$out : "newCollection"}])
```

The indexes from `oldCollection` will not copied in `newCollection` is already known.

But is there any way easiest I can move this directly to a different database in on the same MongoDB host and is there any option to stop overwriting/replacing the entire data in the collection. I mean to retain changes made on the `newColleciton`?

As per MongoDB docs:

> $out stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection. The $out operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. If you really want to export to other database; save the intermediate result somewhere and populate by creating another database which seems a headache though